# Python: How to write a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to write a CSV that outputs the following:

```
John
Titles    Values
color     black
age       15

Laly
Titles    Values
color     pink
age       20

total age 35
```

And so far have:

```
import csv

students_file = open(‘./students_file’, ‘w’)
file_writer = csv.DictWriter(students_file)

…

file_writer.writeheader(name_title) #John
file_writer.writeheader(‘Titles’:’Values’)
file_writer.writerow(color_title:color_val) #In first column: color, in second column: black
file_writer.writerow(age_title:age_val) #In first column: age, in second column: 15
file_writer.writerow('total age': total_val) #In first column: 'total age', in second column: total_val
```

But seems like it just writes on new rows rather than putting corresponding values next to each other.

What is the proper way of creating the example above?

Comment: I would recommend having a look at this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html... Using pandas is really good in most such cases

Comment: I don't think you got the concept of `.csv` right. The `c` stands for comma (or any other delimiter). Think of it as an excel sheet. First line with the col names, then the values. You are not in need to write eg. `age` twice.

Comment: @ansi_lumen Appreciate the response. Aware that it's an excel sheet. In the excel sheet, would like to create the example. Do you mind putting it as an answer? So that I can upvote/accept as well.

Comment: It is Excel like in a more restricted way. Just the column fashion, with header just in the first line.

Comment: @LaurentG Can you show an example?

Comment: Read the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you got the concept of `.csv` right. The `c` stands for comma (or any other delimiter). I guess it means **C**omma,**S**eparated,**V**alues.

Think of it as an excel sheet or a relational database table (eg. MySQL).

Mostly the document starts with a line of col names, then the values follow. You are not in need to write eg. age twice.

Example structure of a `.csv`

```
firstname,lastname,age,favorite_meal
Jim,Joker,33,"fried hamster"
Bert,Uber,19,"salad, vegan"
```

Often text is enclosed in `"` to, so that itself can contain commas and dont't disturb your `.csv` structure.